# UIWebView Performance just for text?

Tags: performance, ios, text, uiwebview, uiscrollview

i want to choose to render formated text in uiwebviews in a scrollview with many pages. there will be up to 10 webviews with just text on one page. when viewing a page, the next and the view behaing are loaded. so when scrolling, there are three pages loaded at a time.

my question is: how's the performance when scrolling the scrollview with the webviews. will it lag? now i use three20 text views for the text and it works flawlessly.

because i don't have the time test the whole stuff with webviews, i just wanted to ask you, if you have any experience with a solution like this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Memory consumption could be an issue on models with lower RAM specs. I don't know how much RAM it needs, but safari doesn't seem to be able to keep many pages in memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience , I have implement 4 UIWebview that load amount of XML data and convert to HTML with objective-c code , and use javascript to manage each pages with javascript that hide/show document.getelementbyId

so, It's quite good for me . I think the performance base on how internet connection speed ,your HTML layout arrangement complexity and managing content javascript.